# Django Tables2 with TemplateColumn the View is not printing the request

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I'm trying to print the request in my view but nothing happens when I click on the 'Editar' button (TemplateColumn), this is what I have in my code:

tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2 import TemplateColumn
from .models import Vencimientos, LogAsistencia

class VencimientosTable(tables.Table):

    asistencia = TemplateColumn(
            '<a class="btn btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url "checkin" record.id %}">Editar</a>')
    class Meta:
        model = Vencimientos
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap5.html"
        fields = ("cliente","vencimiento","activo" )
        attrs = {"class": "table table-hover table-sm"}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    ....
    path('asistencia/<int:pk>/', CheckIn.as_view(), name='checkin')

]
```

views.py

```
class CheckIn(View):

    def get(self, request):
        print(request)
        return redirect ('asistencia')
```

when I click on the "Editar" button in the table the idea is to get the record.id so I can add some extra code, but the button doesn´t do anything

**UPDATE**

I inspect the button and I see the link correct:

[image]

The button doesn´t do anything still

Comment: If you type the URL directly to the browser, do you see the request print out? `http:local/asistencia/<int:pk>/`

Comment: yes, the problem is the button somehow it doesn´t do anything,

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens when you click the link?  Do other unrelated buttons on the page work?

Comment: I also have a search field with a button and it woks, if I click the link in the inspect it does work, it is just that if I click the button directly it does not work

Comment: Interesting. If you haven't, try removing the CSS classes, which should leave just the URL linked. If that works, add back the CSS classes one by one until you find the class that is causing issues.

Comment: You were right there was a problem with a javascript class, it was causing a conflict. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [custom render_ method](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods) to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html

class VencimientosTable(tables.Table):

    asistencia = tables.Column(empty_values=())

    def render_asistencia(self, record):
        url = reverse("checkin", kwargs={"pk": record.id})
        return format_html(f"<a class='btn btn btn-info btn-sm' href='{url}'>Editar</a>")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but I still don´t get any response, it's like it doesn´t reach the view and provide the response